# How to use iot-benmark in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

I am trying to use the IoT Benchmark to evaluate the performance of CNOSDB, an open source time series database similar to InfluxDB. I'm not very familiar with IoT Benchmark yet, and I've been looking through its official documentation for information on how to set up and run performance tests, but I've come across some issues.

Can you provide documentation

Answer (score 0):

For related configuration of linking cnosdb, please refer to [config](https://github.com/thulab/iot-benchmark/blob/master/cnosdb/config.properties),For configuration of other parts, please refer to [config](https://github.com/thulab/iot-benchmark/blob/master/configuration/conf/config.properties).

Hope the above information can help you use iot-bench to test cnosdb